# Возможно ли найти профиль по ID в телеграмме?

Tags: telegram, aiogram

Есть ID человека, который взаимодействовал с ботом и инлайн кнопками.
Существует ли до сих пор какой-то способ позволяющий найти профиль по ID?

```
    await message.answer("<a href='tg://user?id=***'>inline mention of a user</a>", parse_mode='HTML')
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "<a href='tg://user?id=***'>inline mention of a user</a>", parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
```

пробывал так не работает

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/704345

Comment: в aiogram получается как то так?
await message.answer("<a href='tg://user?id=****'>inline mention of a user</a>", parse_mode='HTML')
на текст все равно нельзя нажать ни с веба ни с телефона

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/utils/formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

```
await message.answer("<a href='tg://user?id= 2262526387'>inline mention of a user</a>", parse_mode='HTML')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]